# How to find the points that did not intersect with STIntersect using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I performed STInteract using two tables and the intersections of points onto a given polygon. I have converted all the tables to have geometries for all. I am having a problem writing the query for this. I am trying to look for the points that did not intersect.

These are my two table

- `PO_Database` = contains the points
- `POLY_Database` = Polygon of interest

This is my script:

```
SELECT GEOM 
FROM [dbo].[PO_Database] as PO
JOIN [dbo].[POLY_Database] as p ON hwy.GEOM.STIntersects(p.NEATCELL) = 1
```

I tried changing the value from 1 to 0 but I get repeating values of the geometry for when the query is run with 0. How do I write the query to give me the names of the points that did not intersect with the polygon. Also is there a way to do checks if the intersects where done right.

Answer (score 0):

If you get repeating values, you probably have multiple rows in the `POLY_Database` table. If you want to find the points that do not intersect any of those polygons, try this query:

```
SELECT GEOM 
FROM [dbo].[PO_Database] as PO
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[POLY_Database] as p 
    WHERE hwy.GEOM.STIntersects(p.NEATCELL) = 1
)
```